# Output a string as a sentence

Tags: r, string

I have a lot of strings like these:

```
x1 <- c("Red", "Green", "Blue")
x2 <- c("Red", "Green", "Orange", "Yellow", "Pink")
x3 <- c("Red", "Green")
x4 <- c("Red")
x5 <- c("Red", "Green", "Orange", "Yellow", "Pink", "Blue", "Green")
```

I want to convert them to sentences with these characteristics:

1. lowercase
2. "and" separating second last and last element
3. otherwise "," separating each element
4. if just 2 elements then they should print as "xx and xx"
5. if just 1 element they should print as "xx"

So these strings the strings above should be printed like this:

```
# red, green and blue
# red, green, orange, yellow and pink
# red and green
# red
# red, green, orange, yellow, pink, blue and green
```

I began to make a function to accomplish the above, this is how far I got:

```
sentence_string <- function(x){

    x <- tolower(x)

    x <- paste0(x, sep = ,)

    x

}
```

But cannot figure out how to achieve my desired output. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use `stringi` for these operations,

```
library(stringi)

get_string <- function(x){
  y <- paste(x, collapse = ', ')
  y1 <- tolower(stri_replace_last_regex(y, ',', ' and'))
  return(y1)
}

get_string(x1)
#[1] "red, green and blue"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using only base R:

```
sentence_string <- function(x){
  l <- length(x)
  if (l == 1) {
    tolower(x)
  } else {
    x <- tolower(x)
    y <- paste(x[-l], collapse = ', ')
    paste0(c(y, x[l]), collapse = ' and ')
  }
}
```

giving:

```
> sentence_string(x1)
[1] "red, green and blue"
> sentence_string(x2)
[1] "red, green, orange, yellow and pink"
> sentence_string(x3)
[1] "red and green"
> sentence_string(x4)
[1] "red"
> sentence_string(x5)
[1] "red, green, orange, yellow, pink, blue and green"
```